# How is the shareReplay function working?

Tags: swift, system.reactive, rx-swift

I have read RxSwift/ShareReplayScope.swift file， but a little difficult to understand.

```
public func share(replay: Int = 0, scope: SubjectLifetimeScope = .whileConnected)
        -> Observable<E> {
        switch scope {
        case .forever:
            switch replay {
            case 0: return self.multicast(PublishSubject()).refCount()
            default: return self.multicast(ReplaySubject.create(bufferSize: replay)).refCount()
            }
        case .whileConnected:
            switch replay {
            case 0: return ShareWhileConnected(source: self.asObservable())
            case 1: return ShareReplay1WhileConnected(source: self.asObservable())
            default: return self.multicast(makeSubject: { ReplaySubject.create(bufferSize: replay) }).refCount()
            }
        }
    }
```

0,1 and default,what is the difference? why separate 1 from defalut?

```
 override func subscribe<O : ObserverType>(_ observer: O) -> Disposable where O.E == E {
        _lock.lock()

        let connection = _synchronized_subscribe(observer)
        let count = connection._observers.count
        let disposable = connection._synchronized_subscribe(observer)

        _lock.unlock()

        if count == 0 {
            connection.connect()
        }

        return disposable
    }
```

how the `lock` work, and the most difficult is this function. how the blocked obserables connect to their observers correctly.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8):

Below you get the information about shareReplay function.

**share()**

As you know share function shares the subscription of `Observable`. So that you don't need to create multiple observable instances every time.

Simply create one observable and share replay. it will allow to perform next operation within this sharable observable. i.e `filter()`, `subscribe()`, etc..

But the problem with `share()` is, it is not provide values before subscription.

**shareReplay()**

Where `shareReplay()` keeps a buffer of the last few emitted values and can provide them to new observers upon subscription.

Comment: why not append shareReplay(1) to just any observable?

Comment: @MartinCremer It depends. Each call of subscribe() will trigger it’s own independent execution. So if you ever have a situation that needs the logic to be executed each time a new subscription happens (maybe it's based on the time) then you wouldn't want shareReplay there just feeding the last value(s).